# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: оператор не существует: character varying = bytea

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, criteria, criteriabuilder

Делаю на Spring Boot с Thymeleaf и PostgreSQL CRUD приложение. Для составного `select` запроса на поиск по БД использую Criteria Builder. При нажатии на кнопку `Найти` на странице приложение падает с ошибкой:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: оператор не существует: character varying = bytea
  Подсказка: Оператор с данными именем и типами аргументов не найден. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов.
  Позиция: 165
```

В интернете пишут, что такое может быть, если какие-то поля содержат null, но у меня на все поля стоит проверка на null. Как это исправить, учитывая использование Criteria Builder?
Представление (объект поискового запроса называется `searchRequest`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Собаки</title>
 <style>
   table { 
    width: 100%; 
    border: 4px double black; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
   }
   th { 
    text-align: left; 
    background: #ccc; 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
   }
   td { 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
   }
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
    
<div th:if="${isUserAuth}">Выйти</div>
<div th:unless="${isUserAuth}">Войти</div>
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
 <a href="/logout">Logout</a>  
</div>

<div sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
    <p>Hello, guest! Please <a href="/login">Login</a> or <a href="/signup">SignUp</a></p> 
</div>

<div>Выберите сущность:
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="radio" id="dogChoice" value="dog"/><label for="dogChoice">Собаки</label>
        </form>
</div>
<div><form th:method="POST" th:object:"${searchRequest}" th:action="@{/search}">
    <select th:field="*{searchRequest.tableName}"> 
        <option th:value="dogs">Собаки</option>
        </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="по имени или кличке"/ th:field="*{searchRequest.nicknameOrName}">
    
    <td>Порода:<select th:field="*{searchRequest.breed}">
                <option value="all">Все</option>
                    <option th:each="breedType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Breed).values()}" 
                        th:value="${breedType.name()}" th:text="${breedType.type}"></option>
                </select>
    <td>Пол:<select th:field="*{searchRequest.gender}">
                    <option value="all">Все</option>
                    <option th:each="genderType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Gender).values()}" 
                        th:value="${genderType.name()}" th:text="${genderType.type}"></option>
                </select></td>
            
    <input type="submit" value="Найти"/></form></div>
<table border="1" color="black" border-collapse="collapse">
    <tr>
        <td><b>ID</b></td>
        <td><b>Кличка</b></td>
        <td><b>Имя</b></td>
        <td><b>Пол</b></td>
        <td><b>Порода</b></td>
        <td><b>Дата рождения</b></td>
        <td><b>Щенки</b></td>
        <td><b>Добавлено</b></td>
        <td><b>Изменено</b></td>
        <td>Изменить</td>
        <td>Удалить</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form modelAttribute="dog" th:method="POST" th:object:"${dog}" th:action="@{/}" action="#">
            <td><input type="submit" value="Добавить"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.nickname}"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.name}"/></td>
            <td><select th:field="*{dog.gender}">
                    <option th:each="genderType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Gender).values()}" 
                        th:value="${genderType}" th:text="${genderType.type}"></option>
                </select></td>
            <td><select th:field="*{dog.breed}">
                    <option th:each="breedType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Breed).values()}" 
                        th:value="${breedType}" th:text="${breedType.type}"></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" th:field="*{dog.dateOfBirth}"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" th:field="*{dog.puppies}"/></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="dog : ${dogs}">
            
                <form id="edit" modelAttribute="dog" th:method="DELETE" th:object:"${dog}" th:action="@{/{id}(id=${dog.getId()})}" action="#">
                     
                    <td th:text="${dog.id}"></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.nickname}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.nickname}"><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.nickname}"/></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.name}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.name}"><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.name}"/></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.gender.type}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}"><select th:field="*{dog.gender}">
                            <option th:each="genderType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Gender).values()}" 
                            th:value="${genderType}" th:text="${genderType.type}"></option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.breed.type}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}"><select th:field="*{dog.breed}">
                            <option th:each="breedType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Breed).values()}" 
                                th:value="${breedType}" th:text="${breedType.type}"></option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.dateOfBirth}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}"><input type="date" th:field="*{dog.dateOfBirth}"/></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.puppies}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}"><input type="number" th:field="*{dog.puppies}"/></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.modifiedAt}"></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.createdAt}"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="toedit" value="Изменить" onclick="toEdit()" form="edit"/></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Удалить"</td>                                       
                </form>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                
       
                
        
            </tr>
 </table>
 <script>
        toedit.onclick = function()
            {
                document.getElementById('eachDog').innerHTML = document.getElementById(document.getElementById('edit').value).innerHTML;
                alert("pashet");
            };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Класс поиска:

```
package com.example.demo6.search;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import jakarta.persistence.TypedQuery;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Root;

import com.example.demo6.entities.Dog;

public class Search {
        private static final StringBuilder SELECT = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM ");
        private StringBuilder tableName;
        private Integer id;
        private StringBuilder nicknameOrName;
        private StringBuilder breed;
        private StringBuilder gender;
        private Integer minPuppiesCount;
        private LocalDate dateOfBirthFrom;
        private LocalDate dateOfBirthTo;
        private OffsetDateTime dateOfCreationFrom;
        private OffsetDateTime dateOfCreationTo;
        private OffsetDateTime dateOfModificationFrom;
        private OffsetDateTime dateOfModificationTo;
        private StringBuilder orderBy;
        private Boolean descDirection;
        private StringBuilder query;
        
        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;
        
        
        public Search(){
            this.descDirection = false;
            this.query = SELECT;
        }
        
        public Search(StringBuilder tableName, Integer id, StringBuilder nicknameOrName, StringBuilder breed, StringBuilder gender,
                Integer minPuppiesCount, LocalDate dateOfBirthFrom, LocalDate dateOfBirthTo,
                OffsetDateTime dateOfCreationFrom, OffsetDateTime dateOfCreationTo, OffsetDateTime dateOfModificationFrom,
                OffsetDateTime dateOfModificationTo, StringBuilder orderBy) {
            super();
            this.tableName = tableName;
            this.id = id;
            this.nicknameOrName = nicknameOrName;
            this.breed = breed;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.minPuppiesCount = minPuppiesCount;
            this.dateOfBirthFrom = dateOfBirthFrom;
            this.dateOfBirthTo = dateOfBirthTo;
            this.dateOfCreationFrom = dateOfCreationFrom;
            this.dateOfCreationTo = dateOfCreationTo;
            this.dateOfModificationFrom = dateOfModificationFrom;
            this.dateOfModificationTo = dateOfModificationTo;
            this.orderBy = orderBy;
            this.descDirection = false;
            this.query = SELECT;
            
        }

        
        public List<Dog> getResults() {
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPersistence");
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
            CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Dog> cq = cb.createQuery(Dog.class);
            Root<Dog> root = cq.from(Dog.class);
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            
            if (id != null) predicates.add(cb.like(root.get("id"), "%" + id + "%"));
            if (nicknameOrName != null && !nicknameOrName.isEmpty()) {
                predicates.add(cb.or(
                        cb.like(root.get("nickname"), "%" + nicknameOrName + "%")
                        , cb.like(root.get("name"), "%" + nicknameOrName + "%")
                        ));
            
            }
            if (breed != null && !breed.isEmpty() && breed.toString() != "all") predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("breed"), breed));
            if (gender != null && !gender.isEmpty() && gender.toString() != "all") predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("gender"), gender));
            if (minPuppiesCount != null && minPuppiesCount > 0) predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("minPuppiesCount"), minPuppiesCount));
            if (dateOfBirthFrom != null) predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dateOfBirthFrom"), dateOfBirthFrom));
            if (dateOfBirthTo != null) predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dateOfBirthTo"), dateOfBirthTo));
            if (dateOfCreationFrom != null) predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dateOfCreationFrom"), dateOfCreationFrom));
            if (dateOfCreationTo != null) predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dateOfCreationTo"), dateOfCreationTo));
            if (dateOfModificationFrom != null) predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dateOfModificationFrom"), dateOfModificationFrom));
            if (dateOfModificationTo != null) predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dateOfModificationTo"), dateOfModificationTo));
            if (orderBy != null) {
                if (descDirection != null && descDirection) {
                    cq.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get(orderBy.toString())));
                } else {
                    cq.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(orderBy.toString())));
                }   
            }
            
            if (!predicates.isEmpty()) {
                cq.select(root).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
            } else {
                cq.select(root);
            }
            
            TypedQuery<Dog> typedQuery = em.createQuery(cq);
            return typedQuery.getResultList();
            
        }
        
        public StringBuilder getTableName() {
            return tableName;
        }

        public void setTableName(StringBuilder tableName) {
            this.tableName = tableName;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public StringBuilder getNicknameOrName() {
            return nicknameOrName;
        }

        public void setNicknameOrName(StringBuilder nicknameOrName) {
            this.nicknameOrName = nicknameOrName;
        }

        public StringBuilder getBreed() {
            return breed;
        }

        public void setBreed(StringBuilder breed) {
            this.breed = breed;
        }

        public StringBuilder getGender() {
            return gender;
        }

        public void setGender(StringBuilder gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }

        public Integer getMinPuppiesCount() {
            return minPuppiesCount;
        }

        public void setMinPuppiesCount(Integer minPuppiesCount) {
            this.minPuppiesCount = minPuppiesCount;
        }

        public LocalDate getDateOfBirthFrom() {
            return dateOfBirthFrom;
        }

        public void setDateOfBirthFrom(LocalDate dateOfBirthFrom) {
            this.dateOfBirthFrom = dateOfBirthFrom;
        }

        public LocalDate getDateOfBirthTo() {
            return dateOfBirthTo;
        }

        public void setDateOfBirthTo(LocalDate dateOfBirthTo) {
            this.dateOfBirthTo = dateOfBirthTo;
        }

        public OffsetDateTime getDateOfCreationFrom() {
            return dateOfCreationFrom;
        }

        public void setDateOfCreationFrom(OffsetDateTime dateOfCreationFrom) {
            this.dateOfCreationFrom = dateOfCreationFrom;
        }

        public OffsetDateTime getDateOfCreationTo() {
            return dateOfCreationTo;
        }

        public void setDateOfCreationTo(OffsetDateTime dateOfCreationTo) {
            this.dateOfCreationTo = dateOfCreationTo;
        }

        public OffsetDateTime getDateOfModificationFrom() {
            return dateOfModificationFrom;
        }

        public void setDateOfModificationFrom(OffsetDateTime dateOfModificationFrom) {
            this.dateOfModificationFrom = dateOfModificationFrom;
        }

        public OffsetDateTime getDateOfModificationTo() {
            return dateOfModificationTo;
        }

        public void setDateOfModificationTo(OffsetDateTime dateOfModificationTo) {
            this.dateOfModificationTo = dateOfModificationTo;
        }

        public StringBuilder getOrderBy() {
            return orderBy;
        }

        public void setOrderBy(StringBuilder orderBy) {
            this.orderBy = orderBy;
        }

        public boolean isDescDirection() {
            return descDirection;
        }

        public void setDescDirection(boolean descDirection) {
            this.descDirection = descDirection;
        }

        public void setQuery(StringBuilder query) {
            this.query = query;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Search [tableName=" + tableName + ", id=" + id + ", nicknameOrName=" + nicknameOrName + ", breed="
                    + breed + ", gender=" + gender + ", minPuppiesCount=" + minPuppiesCount + ", dateOfBirthFrom="
                    + dateOfBirthFrom + ", dateOfBirthTo=" + dateOfBirthTo + ", dateOfCreationFrom="
                    + dateOfCreationFrom + ", dateOfCreationTo=" + dateOfCreationTo + ", dateOfModificationFrom="
                    + dateOfModificationFrom + ", dateOfModificationTo=" + dateOfModificationTo + ", orderBy=" + orderBy
                    + ", descDirection=" + descDirection + ", query=" + query
                    + "]";
        }
    }
```

Сервис:

```
package com.example.demo6.service;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.example.demo6.entities.Dog;
import com.example.demo6.repositories.DogRepository;
import com.example.demo6.search.Search;

@Service
public class DogService extends AbstractEntityServiceImpl<Dog, DogRepository> {
    private DogRepository dogRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public DogService(DogRepository repository, DogRepository dogRepository) {
        super(repository);
        this.dogRepository = dogRepository;
        
        
    }
    
    public List<Dog> find(Search searchRequest) {
        return searchRequest.getResults();
    }
        

    public Dog save(Dog dog){
        return dogRepository.save(dog);
    }
    
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public Dog update(int id, Dog updatedDog){
        Dog dogToUpdate = dogRepository.findById((long) id).get();
        System.out.println(dogToUpdate.toString());
        dogToUpdate.setNickname(updatedDog.getNickname());
        dogToUpdate.setName(updatedDog.getName());
        dogToUpdate.setGender(updatedDog.getGender());
        dogToUpdate.setBreed(updatedDog.getBreed());
        dogToUpdate.setDateOfBirth(updatedDog.getDateOfBirth());
        dogToUpdate.setPuppies(updatedDog.getPuppies());
        dogToUpdate.setModifiedAt(OffsetDateTime.now());
        System.out.println(dogToUpdate.toString());
        System.out.println(updatedDog.toString());
        Dog savedDog = dogRepository.save(dogToUpdate);
        System.out.println("done");
        return savedDog;
    }
    
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void delete(int id) {
        dogRepository.deleteById((long) id);
    }
    
    public Dog findById(int id){        
        return dogRepository.findById((long) id).get();
        
    }

    
}
```

Контроллер:

```
package com.example.demo6.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import com.example.demo6.entities.Dog;
import com.example.demo6.search.Search;
import com.example.demo6.service.DogService;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class DogController extends AbstractController<Dog, DogService> {
    private DogService dogService;
    
    @Autowired
    public DogController(DogService service, DogService dogService) {
        super(service);
        this.dogService = dogService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path = {"/search", "", "/"})
    public String index(Model model, @ModelAttribute("searchRequest") Search searchRequest) {
            model.addAttribute("searchRequest", new Search());
            model.addAttribute("dog", new Dog());
            model.addAttribute("dogs", dogService.find(searchRequest));
            return "index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String edit(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
        model.addAttribute("dog", dogService.findById(id));
        return "editdog";
        
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/search")
    public String search(Model model, @ModelAttribute("searchRequest") Search searchRequest) {
        model.addAttribute("dogs", dogService.find(searchRequest));
        return "redirect:";
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("dog")@Valid Dog dog, Model model) { 
        dogService.save(dog);
        return "redirect:";
    }
    
    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public String update(@ModelAttribute("dog")@Valid Dog updatedDog, @PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {    
        dogService.update(id, updatedDog);
        return "redirect:";
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        dogService.delete(id);
        return "redirect:";
    }
}
```

UPD изменил следующий код:

```
if (breed != null && !breed.isEmpty() && breed.toString() != "all") predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("breed"), breed));
            if (gender != null && !gender.isEmpty() && gender.toString() != "all") predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("gender"), gender));
            if (minPuppiesCount != null && minPuppiesCount > 0) predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("minPuppiesCount"), minPuppiesCount));
            if (dateOfBirthFrom != null) predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dateOfBirthFrom"), dateOfBirthFrom));
            if (dateOfBirthTo != null) predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dateOfBirthTo"), dateOfBirthTo));
            if (dateOfCreationFrom != null) predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dateOfCreationFrom"), dateOfCreationFrom));
            if (dateOfCreationTo != null) predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dateOfCreationTo"), dateOfCreationTo));
            if (dateOfModificationFrom != null) predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dateOfModificationFrom"), dateOfModificationFrom));
            if (dateOfModificationTo != null) predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dateOfModificationTo"), dateOfModificationTo));
            if (orderBy != null) {
                if (descDirection != null && descDirection) {
                    cq.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get(orderBy.toString())));
                } else {
                    cq.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(orderBy.toString())));
                }   
            }
```

На:

```
if (breed != null && !breed.isEmpty() && breed.toString() != "all") predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("breed"), breed));
            if (gender != null && !gender.isEmpty() && gender.toString() != "all") predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("gender"), gender));
            if (minPuppiesCount != null && minPuppiesCount > 0) predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("puppies"), minPuppiesCount));
            if (dateOfBirthFrom != null) predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dateOfBirth"), dateOfBirthFrom));
            if (dateOfBirthTo != null) predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dateOfBirth"), dateOfBirthTo));
            if (dateOfCreationFrom != null) predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("createdAt"), dateOfCreationFrom));
            if (dateOfCreationTo != null) predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("createdAt"), dateOfCreationTo));
            if (dateOfModificationFrom != null) predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("modifiedAt"), dateOfModificationFrom));
            if (dateOfModificationTo != null) predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("modifiedAt"), dateOfModificationTo));
            if (orderBy != null) {
                if (descDirection) {
                    cq.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get(orderBy.toString())));
                } else {
                    cq.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(orderBy.toString())));
                }   
            }
```

То есть поменял параметры методов `root.get()`.

Comment: Я дуб. Кажись я в классе поиска ищу по самому классу поиска, а не по классу сущности. Сейчас попробую исправить.

Comment: Попробовал - не сработало.

Comment: Не имеет отношения к null. Имеет отношение к типам данных. Где-то в полученном запросе, вы пытаетесь сравнить значение типа varchar со значением типа bytea. С точки зрения postgresql это сравнение невозможно выполнить однозначным способом и функции сравнения этих типов данных нет. Проверяйте в первую очередь свои where, какие типы данных в таблице, а какие типы данных вы передаёте как параметры в запросе.

Comment: Действительно, ошибка оказалась в этих строках и `if (breed != null && !breed.isEmpty() && breed.toString() != "all") predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("breed"), breed));
            if (gender != null && !gender.isEmpty() && gender.toString() != "all") predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("gender"), gender)); ` Связана с приведением enum к строке. Но как в этом месте получить строку из enum'а не знаю, ведь он указывается в двойных кавычках. Но все равно спасибо.

Comment: Решил проблему. Заменил `(root.get("breed"), breed) ` на `(root.get("breed"), Dog.Breed.valueOf(breed.toString()))`